# Unsure about 90s movie that had black sludge that broke through an astronauts helmet?

Tags: story-identification, horror

It's a movie from the 90s. I was pretty young when I first watched it, but from what I can remember.. it was like a black sludge that broke through an astronauts helmet and went inside his body.  After that, it took control of him and plenty others the same way. Then a team found a giant one in the sewers of a city. I know it's not much information,  but that's all I can remember.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like [Phantoms(1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119891/)

It's only one entity and technically they aren't astronauts but the hazmat suits do look like space suits.