# Looking for a science fiction movie with tentacles and a cure?

Tags: story-identification

I saw this movie as a kid so I can only recall certain scenes from it but the general idea is that some kind of tentacle alien invaded a town and a team of scientists and soldiers were sent there to contain it.

The most vivid scene I remember is when the tentacle oozed through the streets and grabbed a scientist wearing a white hazmat suit by the legs and filled his suit with some black liquid up to the top. He then fell down, his hazmat helmet glass broke, then momentarily woke up and spoke some dialogues before dying for good.

Another scene involves one of the main characters walking through the street back to the research trailer when he was stopped by a dog (which is probably infected with the tentacle). He then said something along the line of "I just want to help out humanity" or something similar before the dog lets him continue on. I think they were trying to research a cure or something to fight the alien with at this point.

Comment: [Love the tentacle](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Yivo)!

Comment: [These aren't tentacles. They're gentacles!](http://basementrejects.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/futurama-the-beast-with-a-billion-backs-2008-review-fry-possessed-by-yivo-love-the-tentacle-pope-600x300.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description reminds me of *Phantoms* (1998). It has tentacles, soldiers, scientists, a dog and black ooze.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantoms_(film))
[imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119891/)

Trailer:

Tentacles at 2:13

NB: This might be a duplicate of [Unsure about 90s movie that had black sludge that broke through an astronauts helmet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53776/unsure-about-90s-movie-that-had-black-sludge-that-broke-through-an-astronauts-he/53791#53791)

Comment: Fruitbat, THANK YOU. That is indeed the movie. I posted the question as a guest now I have no idea how to up vote and accept the answer.

Comment: @Decrypto - Upvote using the up triangle on the left (next to the answer title) and accept using the little tick in the middle.

Comment: @Decrypto It may be worth mentioning that the movie is based off a Dean Koontz novel.

Answer (score 0):

It also sounds like what happens to one of the guys it the 1988 version of The Blob. However, the Blob was pink and it was coming from the sewers when that scene happened.

Comment: Can you explain how this movie is similar to the one in the question? Your answer mainly concentrates on how it is **not** similar.

Comment: The 1988 version of The Blob has tentacles and the military has to come in to try to destroy it. There were people in the movie that wore hazmat suits and One of those people get grabbed by it and his suit gets filled with the blob.

Comment: However, I did not mean to make my answer in the manner that it wasn't similar.